# Remove directory and files after installation using Wix

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

During installation i need some extra files in Custom Actions that are configured in the InstallExecuteSequence tag asl After="InstallFinalize".

After the usage of the files, i want the files (and the directory) to be removed.

How can i do this?

My InstallExecuteSequence lookst like this:

```
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action="UNINSTALLSERVICE"
             After="InstallInitialize">REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
     <Custom Action="CLEANUP"
             Before="RemoveFiles">REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
     <Custom Action="INSTALLSERVICE"
             After="InstallFinalize" />
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

If i create a custom action with

```
ExeCommand="cmd /C RD "somedir" /s /q"
```

and add it to the sequence like this:

```
 <Custom Action="CLEANTEMP" After="InstallFinalize" />
```

I get a build-error:

```
Error   596 ICE77: CLEANCONFIG is a in-script custom action.  
It must be sequenced in between the InstallInitialize action 
and the InstallFinalize action in the InstallExecuteSequence table
```

Comment: Temporary files during installation is a "deployment smell". What are these files doing? There are likely better ways that will be simpler for you.

Comment: In case you are not aware, WiX creates a Windows Installer package. (WiX is not involved in the actual installation.) You should research the design principles of Windows Installer.

Comment: The temporary files are used to configure the config files based on the server they are installed on. The setup is used in our DTAP environment, and are used to automatically install on different machines with different configuration files. All configuration files for all servers in the DTAP environment are included in the setup. And based on the servername, some are used, others not. At the end of the installation, i do not need all config files anymore, and want the directory to be removed.

Comment: I'm not saying my solution is the best solution, but (sorry for saying this), I'm not asking if what I do is wrong (maybe in your eyes i'm completely stupid to do this like i do this), I'm just asking how to remove a directory with contents after installation.

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE**: Not sure why this was down-voted just now. The summary below is sound advice.
>   Perhaps it is the lack of a sample? I'll add a couple of links. Also:
>   there can be cases where a custom action is needed to tweak service
>   installations, but that is rarely necessary if you design the service
>   properly - WiX also has constructs to help you for common tweaks:
>
> - **Phil Wilson's** samples from his book (many further samples for other topics one level up):
>     https://github.com/Apress/def-guide-to-win-installer/tree/master/Chapter10.
> - **Phil Wilson** again with his [Installing Services with Visual Studio sample](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/tips.htm#SvcInstall).
> - **Chris Painter** and his IsWiX tutorials: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials.

---

**There is generally no need to use custom actions to install and configure services.** The built-in MSI features for this are vastly superior due to its full rollback support and extensive feature set. Using custom actions greatly complicates things, adds unnecessary risk and will almost always fail during rollback leaving the system in an invalid state.

There is a learning curve with the MSI tables - there are a lot of options, but in my experience only a few bundles of settings make sense together. Generally stopping and restarting during install and stopping and deleting on uninstall and variations on those. In the past I have added custom actions just to wait whilst the service shuts down properly, but that is just a wait custom action and doesn't change the system. There may be new Wix features for this kind of scenario that I am unaware of.

The MSI tables [ServiceInstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371637(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ServiceControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371634(v=vs.85).aspx) are used to install services. In Wix you deal with the equivalent XML elements: [Wix ServiceInstall](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html) and [Wix ServiceControl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html) and the newer [Wix ServiceConfig](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceconfig.html) and [Wix ServiceConfigFailureActions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceconfigfailureactions.html).

Comment: Glytzhof, my question is not about installing/uninstalling services, but about removing some files i need during installation (no need to go into why i need them, i just do). I just want to remove some files i need during setup, but not after isntallation.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with the way you seem to have set up things:

- Custom actions after InstallFinalize are not to change the system, and they will not be able to run with admin rights. In addition you have set the custom action to be deferred mode, and this is only allowed between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize - which is what the error message you refer to is about.
- Some people use immediate mode custom actions after InstallFinalize. This is by definition always an error, and will only work if the entire setup is run with admin rights. Even then it will most often fail when distributed with SCCM or other software distribution systems in the corporate world.
- Using temporary files during installation is generally undesirable. It is a "deployment smell" as I commented above. Some uses are OK, such as displaying logos and license agreements, but these also tend to be compiled into the setup and removed automagically.
- Running batch files as part of installation is very unreliable and error prone, and may make changes to the system that can not be rolled-back should the setup fail during installation.

The **[RemoveFile table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371201(v=vs.85).aspx)** ([Wix equivalent](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html)) will allow you to remove files during installation, uninstallation or both. You should not remove files that are part of an associated Windows Installer component, as self-repair may put them back.

I believe, that what you need is:

1. A serious rethink of your use of batch files and temporary files. Most likely they are more trouble than they are worth.
2. A full understanding of elevated rights and Windows Installer's security model and the difference between [immediate mode](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=17211) (user rights) and [deferred mode](http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=15386) (elevated rights) custom actions. [**Here is a good article**](http://www.installshield.com/news/newsletter/0308-articles/CustomActionData.asp) by a recognized MSI expert. ***Update 2021-09-04:** Original link appears to be dead. [Here is the link via Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20070417012037/http://www.installshield.com/news/newsletter/0308-articles/CustomActionData.asp).*

Comment: Thanks Glytzhkof. I fully understand what you are saying. And i completely agree with you. So i would say to all users of Wix to not use the setups as I do. But in my case the setups are part of a DTAP environment. And is part of a fully automated service running within our domain. The setups are not shipped to customers etc. etc. they are only maintained by me. And the installation is fully monitored. So on one hand i agree with you, on the other hand, i want to remove some files after finishing the installation.