# How to remove the folder that created after uninstalling the setup?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.10

Created an installer and setup project using wix. After uninstalling the setup the folders that created are not removed. Given install location C:\Program Files(x86)\Setup\msi1\features.
 setup\msi\features are created while installing the setup but only features folder was removed after uninstall. 
Let me know how to remove all created folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove directory and files after installation using Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734775/remove-directory-and-files-after-installation-using-wix)

Comment: Do you have any custom actions? Do you have files set to be permanently installed? Do you generate any folders at runtime?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I dont have ant custom actions to remove the files. Yes while runtime few components with folders are generated i.e.  c:\Program files(x86)\Setup\msi1\feature\Feature1\component1.txt,  c:\Program files(x86)\Setup\msi1\feature\Feature2\component2.txt